# Where can I find NSFormatter example that implements NSTextField masks

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield, nsformatter

In **Qt** and in **C#**, I am able to easily define a input mask for things like phone numbers and serial numbers.  Everything I have read so far leads me to believe that **NSFormatter** is the answer, but I am having trouble finding a complete example that does not suck. I really want to create a formatter for serial numbers that uses dashes between the segments and also limits the characters to a-z and 0-9.  I want to be able to type over the dashes, copy and paste etc.

**Example:** ABC12-34DEF-GH567-890IJ-KL123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not complete, the best example I’ve found was on [CocoaDev: MaskedTextField](http://cocoadev.com/MaskedTextField).

If you feel like this should be a Cocoa feature, consider [filing an enhancement request with Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: This is probably the closest answer aside from sub classing a control that I could find. I did have trouble making it work, but I think it is lack of experience rather than an incorrect answer.

Comment: The link is dead. Could someone please post an approximation of the code from it?